# ¿Cómo instalar python 3 en Linux trisquel?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Trisquel tiene python 2 preinstalado, pero necesito python 3, alguien sabe cual es el comando para terminal para instalar python 3 y de paso si es posible desinstalar python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la documentación de esa *distro* (basada en Ubuntu, por cierto) están las indicaciones para instalar cualquier paquete: https://trisquel.info/es/wiki/instalar-actualizar-y-remover-software

> **Nota importante**
>   Como cualquier distro basada en Ubuntu, Trisquel confía en Python 2 para realizar una serie de tareas a nivel sistema operativo, por lo que **no es conveniente eliminarla**.

Existe una alternativa que te permite experimentar con cualquier versión de Python en tu propio espacio, sin afectar a los archivos del sistema, ya que todo se instala en tu propio directorio `home`.

https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

En este enlace https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer encontrarás el instalador.

### Edición

Parece que es necesario aclarar un poco mi respuesta. `pyenv` no es una versión de Python, sino que permite instalar varias versiones de Python sin que existan conflictos, eso incluye anaconda.

Esta es la lista versiones disponibles para instalar:

```
[toledano ~/proyectos]$ pyenv install --list
Available versions:
  2.1.3
  2.2.3
  2.3.7
  2.4
  2.4.1
  2.4.2
  2.4.3
  2.4.4
  2.4.5
  2.4.6
  2.5
  2.5.1
  2.5.2
  2.5.3
  2.5.4
  2.5.5
  2.5.6
  2.6.6
  2.6.7
  2.6.8
  2.6.9
  2.7-dev
  2.7
  2.7.1
  2.7.2
  2.7.3
  2.7.4
  2.7.5
  2.7.6
  2.7.7
  2.7.8
  2.7.9
  2.7.10
  2.7.11
  2.7.12
  3.0.1
  3.1
  3.1.1
  3.1.2
  3.1.3
  3.1.4
  3.1.5
  3.2-dev
  3.2
  3.2.1
  3.2.2
  3.2.3
  3.2.4
  3.2.5
  3.2.6
  3.3.0
  3.3-dev
  3.3.1
  3.3.2
  3.3.3
  3.3.4
  3.3.5
  3.3.6
  3.4.0
  3.4-dev
  3.4.1
  3.4.2
  3.4.3
  3.4.4
  3.4.5
  3.5.0
  3.5-dev
  3.5.1
  3.5.2
  3.6.0a1
  3.6.0a3
  3.6-dev
  anaconda-1.4.0
  anaconda-1.5.0
  anaconda-1.5.1
  anaconda-1.6.0
  anaconda-1.6.1
  anaconda-1.7.0
  anaconda-1.8.0
  anaconda-1.9.0
  anaconda-1.9.1
  anaconda-1.9.2
  anaconda-2.0.0
  anaconda-2.0.1
  anaconda-2.1.0
  anaconda-2.2.0
  anaconda-2.3.0
  anaconda-2.4.0
  anaconda-4.0.0
  anaconda2-2.4.0
  anaconda2-2.4.1
  anaconda2-2.5.0
  anaconda2-4.0.0
  anaconda2-4.1.0
  anaconda3-2.0.0
  anaconda3-2.0.1
  anaconda3-2.1.0
  anaconda3-2.2.0
  anaconda3-2.3.0
  anaconda3-2.4.0
  anaconda3-2.4.1
  anaconda3-2.5.0
  anaconda3-4.0.0
  anaconda3-4.1.0
  ironpython-dev
  ironpython-2.7.4
  ironpython-2.7.5
  jython-dev
  jython-2.5.0
  jython-2.5-dev
  jython-2.5.1
  jython-2.5.2
  jython-2.5.3
  jython-2.5.4-rc1
  jython-2.7.0
  jython-2.7.1b1
  jython-2.7.1b2
  jython-2.7.1b3
  miniconda-latest
  miniconda-2.2.2
  miniconda-3.0.0
  miniconda-3.0.4
  miniconda-3.0.5
  miniconda-3.3.0
  miniconda-3.4.2
  miniconda-3.7.0
  miniconda-3.8.3
  miniconda-3.9.1
  miniconda-3.10.1
  miniconda-3.16.0
  miniconda-3.18.3
  miniconda2-latest
  miniconda2-3.18.3
  miniconda2-3.19.0
  miniconda2-4.0.5
  miniconda3-latest
  miniconda3-2.2.2
  miniconda3-3.0.0
  miniconda3-3.0.4
  miniconda3-3.0.5
  miniconda3-3.3.0
  miniconda3-3.4.2
  miniconda3-3.7.0
  miniconda3-3.8.3
  miniconda3-3.9.1
  miniconda3-3.10.1
  miniconda3-3.16.0
  miniconda3-3.18.3
  miniconda3-3.19.0
  miniconda3-4.0.5
  pypy-c-jit-latest
  pypy-c-nojit-latest
  pypy-dev
  pypy-stm-2.3
  pypy-portable-2.3.1
  pypy-portable-2.4
  pypy-portable-2.5
  pypy-portable-2.5.1
  pypy-stm-2.5.1
  pypy-portable-2.6
  pypy-portable-2.6.1
  pypy-portable-4.0
  pypy-portable-4.0.1
  pypy-portable-5.0
  pypy-portable-5.0.1
  pypy-portable-5.1
  pypy-portable-5.1.1
  pypy-portable-5.3.1
  pypy-1.5-src
  pypy-1.5
  pypy-1.6
  pypy-1.7-dev
  pypy-1.7
  pypy-1.8-dev
  pypy-1.8
  pypy-1.9-dev
  pypy-1.9
  pypy-2.0-dev
  pypy-2.0-src
  pypy-2.0
  pypy-2.0.1-src
  pypy-2.0.1
  pypy-2.0.2-src
  pypy-2.0.2
  pypy-2.1-src
  pypy-2.1
  pypy-2.2-src
  pypy-2.2
  pypy-2.2.1-src
  pypy-2.2.1
  pypy-2.3-src
  pypy-2.3
  pypy-2.3.1-src
  pypy-2.3.1
  pypy-2.4.0-src
  pypy-2.4.0
  pypy-2.4-beta1-src
  pypy-2.4-beta1
  pypy-2.5.0-src
  pypy-2.5.0
  pypy-2.5.1-src
  pypy-2.5.1
  pypy-2.6.0-src
  pypy-2.6.0
  pypy-2.6.1-src
  pypy-2.6.1
  pypy-4.0.0-src
  pypy-4.0.0
  pypy-4.0.1-src
  pypy-4.0.1
  pypy-5.0.0-src
  pypy-5.0.0
  pypy-5.0.1-src
  pypy-5.0.1
  pypy-5.1-src
  pypy-5.1
  pypy-5.1.1-src
  pypy-5.1.1
  pypy-5.3-src
  pypy-5.3
  pypy-5.3.1
  pypy3-dev
  pypy3-portable-2.3.1
  pypy3-portable-2.4
  pypy3-2.3.1-src
  pypy3-2.3.1
  pypy3-2.4.0-src
  pypy3-2.4.0
  pypy3.3-5.2-alpha1-src
  pypy3.3-5.2-alpha1
  stackless-dev
  stackless-2.7-dev
  stackless-2.7.2
  stackless-2.7.3
  stackless-2.7.4
  stackless-2.7.5
  stackless-2.7.6
  stackless-2.7.7
  stackless-2.7.8
  stackless-3.2-dev
  stackless-3.2.2
  stackless-3.2.5
  stackless-3.3-dev
  stackless-3.3.5
  stackless-3.4.1
```

Comment: Por complementar la respuesta de @toledano, también existe [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) y [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). El primero te instala una distribución de Python (Python + un montón de librerías útiles para hacer cálculo numérico/científico). El segundo te instala solo Python y el gestor de paquetes `conda` (algo parecido a `pip`). Ambas herramientas te instalan Python en tu usuario por lo que no afecta a las instalaciones del sistema. Otra opción sería [Pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz).